# Is it possible to add a gps directions to the camera view for an application?

Tags: java, android, gps, android-camera, windows-mobile-gps

I am currently thinking of developing an android application for my final year project and i was thinking of developing an app that you enter a location and point your camera at a street and using image regonision it will show you where to go on the camera(kinda like what google street view is like).

My question is, is it possible to add in these directions onto the camera screen on the phone when the camera is running and would this be difficult to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible, but for this , you need to write your own code, this code will fetch gps periodically & will display on your custom camera screen.

Comment: I know google has an API for its google maps, do you know if you would be able to link this in to get the directions for the camera?

Comment: oh ok, the application you are talking about is already available ready made dear